# Word to describe removal of prefix

Tags: verbs, clipping

I am describing a two-way process using "*prefix*" as a verb:

- The first action is that of adding a prefix to something.
- The second is the act of removing that same prefix.

If I am describing the first as:

- "Prefix [noun]"

How do I describe the second in the same format, with a single replacement verb for *"prefix"*:

- "[Remove the prefix from] [noun]"

Comment: Unprefix? Truncate?

Comment: The more general process of identifying the root of an inflected word is ***stemming***.

Comment: **Back-formation**, perhaps.

Comment: You could coin 'defix', and then the derivations 'preficate', 'sufficate' and 'deficate' ;)

Comment: @AmI *Deficate* is a little too close for comfort...

Answer (score 4):

**Clipping** (morphology) — [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clipping_(morphology))

> In linguistics, clipping is the word formation process which consists in the reduction of a word to one of its parts (Marchand: 1969). Clipping is also known as "truncation" or "shortening."
> ...
>
> Clipping is different from back-formation – back-formation may change the part of speech or the word's meaning, whereas clipping creates shortened words from longer words, but does not change the part of speech or the meaning of the word.
> ...
>
> According to Irina Arnold (ru) (1986), clipping mainly consists of the following types:
>
> - Initial clipping
> - Final clipping
> - Medial clipping
> - Complex clipping

And in your case, it might be called **Initial clipping**

> Initial (or fore) clipping retains the final part of the prototype.
>
> Examples: bot (robot), chute (parachute), roach (cockroach), coon (raccoon), gator (alligator), phone (telephone), pike (turnpike), varsity (university), net (Internet).